# Extremely low downloading speed on ubuntu but good on windows

Tags: internet, 17.04, download-speed

I have shifted from windows to ubuntu 17.04. I'm getting very low downloading speed on ubuntu. browsing speed is good but downloading is very slow max upto 10KB/s.

While on windows it is 100-180 KB/s. all downloads face same speed either i use chrome, uget firefox or anything.

Hardware:
HP_pavilion core i7 7th generation.

ADAPTER INFORMATION:
"05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:24fb] (rev 10)
    DeviceName: Intel Dual BandWireless-AC 3168 802.11 ac 1x1 WiFi + BT 4.0 Combo Adapter
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2110]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
"

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue on my Acer. We have the same onboard wireless card..

Check if you have updated `linux-firmware` package.

After doing that it improved the speeds a bit for me (20-30 kbPs to ~ 100-200 kBps )

Comment: Also, is secure boot enabled? for some reason (I have absolutely no idea why), disabling secure boot seems to solve it. Now I am getting my full 1 mBps speeds.